# Replace string with numerical value while preserving NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a case of needing to replace string values across a number of columns:

1. The value to substitute changes per column
2. I need to preserve existing NaN

I have a series of steps that seems that it should work, to me, but does not; the 'inplace' step does not work. Some dummy test code:

## make a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 'foo']],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

calculate substitute value, say from last column

```
special_value = pd.to_numeric(df['D'], errors='corece').min() / 2
special_value
```

```
0.5
```

## have a look

```
df
```

## seems to work here

```
pd.to_numeric(df['D'].dropna(), errors='coerce').fillna(value=special_value)
```

```
1    1.0
2    5.0
3    0.5
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

## but no, it doesn't

```
pd.to_numeric(df['D'].dropna(), errors='coerce').fillna(value=special_value, inplace = True)
```

```
0    NaN
1      1
2      5
3    foo
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: What is the code you shared meant to demonstrate? _the 'inplace' step does not work._ Isn't using `inplace=True` strongly discouraged, anyway? IIRC they're likely going to get rid of it.

Comment: I have added outputs, to show that the code I shared demonstrates the lack of working-ness (based on what I might have expected!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.fillna`, it is not going to preserve NaN values.

Try this:

```
def add_value(df,col):
    condition = df[col].apply(lambda x : True if type(x) == int else False) 
    sp_value = df[col][condition].min()/2 
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : sp_value if type(x) == str else x)
```

output is

```
add_value(df,'D')

   A    B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1.0
2   NaN NaN NaN 5.0
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 0.5
```

Comment: Yes, I special_value runs without error; see my edits to question

Comment: @Shawn First, I know why I have an error now. You typo on the error arg `errors='corece'`.  And for the `inplace` , I think it is about `pd.to_numeric`. It returns a new `Series`, not updating the original data. So, when you call `.fillna`, it applies to the new data. The solution should be `df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'].dropna(), errors='coerce').fillna(special_value)`